# Monitor battery charge with Win32 API

Tags: c++, c, winapi, monitor, power-management

I'm trying to write a small app that monitors how much power is left in a notebook battery and I'd like to know which Win32 function I could use to accomplish that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Vista and up you can use [RegisterPowerSettingNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373196(VS.85).aspx)

For earlier functions see the [Power Management Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373163(VS.85).aspx) in this section of the MSDN page "Power Management Functions: Windows Server 2003 and Earlier"

You can see example code of the Vista method on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/VGPowerMonitor.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I recommend the use of the Win32 [GetSystemPowerStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. A code snippet :

```
int getBatteryLevel()
{
    SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS status;
    GetSystemPowerStatus(&status);
    return status.BatteryLifePercent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very detailed article in the following link, as well as a n example project (tested working on Win8.1): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15829/Vista-Goodies-in-C-Monitoring-the-Computer-s-Power

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for [`PBT_APMPOWERSTATUSCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/pbt-apmpowerstatuschange).
This event is triggered in the following 3 scenarios.

1. Battery life drops to less than 5 minutes of power, or
2. Battery life falls below 10%,
3. Battery life changes by 3%

The ideal way is to call  [GetSystemPowerStatus()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getsystempowerstatus) on receiving this event, rather than polling continuously. The `BatteryLifePercent` member of `SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS` will give battery life in percentages.

For this event, you will have to handle the [`WM_POWERBROADCAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/wm-powerbroadcast) message. For `PBT_APMPOWERSTATUSCHANGE` wParam will be `PBT_APMPOWERSTATUSCHANGE`