# QT widget for on WindowsXP

Tags: qt, widget, windows-xp

I need to create a widget which shows battery status(in percentage) inside my qt application. Can anybody suggest me how to get the winXP api to know the battery status. Then as the api will return the percentage I will display on my widget....

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233446/monitor-battery-charge-with-win32-api .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the function you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372693%28v=VS.85%29.aspx