# How do I get battery information in windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

I have two laptops here. One is running Vista, the other Windows 7. I need to get the specifications on the batteries in both, how do I go about that?

The reason I'm asking is that I'd like to know if they're lithium ion or something else. Supposedly other types of batteries may have adversely affected charge capacities if left plugged in for too long.

Comment: Maybe this is a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233446/monitor-battery-charge-with-win32-api

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx) and the [Win32_Battery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394074(VS.85).aspx) class. It has a property called `Chemistry` that has this information.

**UPDATE:**

Actually, there is also [Win32_PortableBattery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394357(VS.85).aspx), which would be more appropriate for a laptop battery. They both inherit from the [CIM_Battery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387189(VS.85).aspx) class.

Answer (score 5):

The [IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372661(v=VS.85).aspx) info from [DeviceIOControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216(v=VS.85).aspx) can tell you the following info:

Information level

- BatteryDeviceName
- BatteryEstimatedTime
- BatteryGranularityInformation
- **BatteryInformation**
- BatteryManufactureDate
- BatteryManufactureName
- BatterySerialNumber
- BatteryTemperature
- BatteryUniqueID

The [BatteryInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372661(v=VS.85).aspx) structure contains the Chemistry field which describes this info you require.

- PbAc : Lead Acid
- LION : Lithium Ion
- Li-I : Lithium Ion
- NiCd : Nickel Cadmium
- NiMH : Nickel Metal Hydride
- NiZn : Nickel Zinc
- RAM  : Rechargeable Alkaline-Manganese

There is an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204769(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Does anybody have c# implementation of the above classes? I mean I do not Manufacturer information from Win32_Battery class

Comment: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.deviceiocontrol

Answer (score 3):

If you're using managed code (C# or VB) the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) has a wrapper class that raises .NET events when power events (going on or off AC, reaching critical battery level etc) happen and exposes properties like estimated battery life remaining. It also includes a whole pile of gory details - the sample shows them.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a interesting link:
http://www.nextofwindows.com/find-out-how-healthy-your-battery-is-on-your-windows-7-laptop/
command described there

**powercfg -energy**

will produce you a nice report with many details about your battery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**`powercfg -energy`**

Run this command on cmd as administrator mode.It will create a report as HTML file in your administrator path. Open that file and here you will get everything you want about your battery.