# How to get battery status in windows 7 via some api?

Tags: c#, windows-7, battery

i want to know is there any way to know by c# code that laptop's battery is fully charged or is there any event raised when the battery is full.

Comment: You might want to read the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154554/how-do-i-get-battery-information-in-windows?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you could use the WMI class [Win32_Battery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There are multiple fields that could be useful - `DesignCapacity`, `BatteryStatus`, `FullChargeCapacity` or `ExpectedLife`

So my guess is that you can use WMI to read these two values, and then calculate `FullChargeCapacity/BatteryStatus/DesignCapacity/ExpectedLife` to find the battery health percentage number.

Comment: i want to write an alaram app, that signals when the battery gets fully charged. i have no concern with its health

Comment: Yes but you can use it to tell when it is fully charged when using a comparision, then you can do your alarm or whatever.

Comment: @user1783761 - What you want is possible just look at the class in question.  You can use `BatteryStatus` and `ExpectedLife` to acomplish your goal.