# Can I write a c program that actually alerts about my laptop battery?

Tags: batterymanager

Is it possible to write in C to get the alert. If yes, what is the concept to be applied to get an alert when my battery goes down by 40% or gets high to 80%?

Comment: It depends on the OS you're running on. For a gist on how to do this on Windows check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233446/monitor-battery-charge-with-win32-api

Comment: Your OS might contain an appropriate API for this. If one of the newer Windows, then the "check this one out" above will help.

Comment: The simplest answer might be that your laptop probably already has a program that does this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Windows API to get the battery information. Please refer to the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372659(v=vs.85).aspx

The following ioctls are used to get the battery information

> IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_INFORMATION
>
> IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_STATUS
>
> IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_TAG
>
> IOCTL_BATTERY_SET_INFORMATION

`GetSystemPowerStatus` function is used to get the power status in windows. Refer to the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372693(v=vs.85).aspx